# Spring Integration - Service Activator in Java DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a service activator configured in a simple POJO and I want to convert it into Java DSL.

Right now, my Java DSL looks like this,

```
public IntegrationFlow inputFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel())
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "com.dash.messages")
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(MessageWrapper.class, customObjectMapper()))
            .channel(theOtherChannel()))
            .get();
  }
```

There is a POJO with a service activator in it,

```
public class MessageProcessor {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageProcessor.class);

  ....

  @ServiceActivator
  public void handle(MessageWrapper message, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
    logger.debug("Message received: " + message);
    
    // Send message to another system
    ....
  }

}
```

In XML, the corresponding configuration is as shown below,

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="theOtherChannel"
        ref="MessageProcessor" output-channel="nullChannel" />
```

1. How do I invoke the ServiceActivator method in Java DSL? I am thinking of using `.handle()`, but what should be the argument(s)?
2. Is there any concept of a `null` channel when using Java DSL? If yes, how do we specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this `handle()` variant:

```
/**
 * Populate a {@link ServiceActivatingHandler} for the
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor}
 * to invoke the discovered {@code method} for provided {@code service} at runtime.
 * @param service the service object to use.
 * @return the current {@link BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 */
public B handle(Object service) {
```

So, you just need to autowire your `MessageProcessor` into the class with that `IntegrationFlow` definition or directly to that `inputFlow()` bean definition. then you do just this:

```
.channel(theOtherChannel()))
.handle(messageProcessor)
.get();
```

There is no need in `nullChannel` for service activator with `void` return type. The flow is just going to stop at that point anyway when it encounters with `void` or `null` reply.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-handle

Comment: That did it. Thanks!